# Why isn't the svg arrow in the background css showing?

Tags: css, svg, background-image

I am unable to get to show the svg in the background of the selector when I use this css.

But the svg is rendered when I put it in an image tag .
Even other svg are rendered when added to the background of the selector.
I want this one and it is not showing.

```
      <select
        name="warehouse"
        id="warehouse"
        onChange={(e) => props.setSelected(e.target.value)}
        className="Selector"
        >
        
         <option className="Option" value={item1} />
         <option className="Option" value={item2} />
       
     </select>
```

```
.Selector {
    padding: 0.2vw 2vw 0.2vw 2vw;
  
 /* adding new arrow */

    background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="8" height="5" viewBox="0 0 8 5" fill="black" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M0.94 0L4 3.09042L7.06 0L8 0.951417L4 5L0 0.951417L0.94 0Z" fill="black"/></svg>");
    background-position-x: 5px !important;
    background-position-y: 5px !important;

 /* remove pre existing arrow*/

    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    -moz-appearance: none !important;
    -ms-appearance: none !important;
    -o-appearance: none !important;
    appearance: none !important;
  }
```

Comment: Because you need to sort out the double quotes. If your SVG data contains double quotes then you have to use single quotes for the url i.e. background url('data... otherwise the parser doesn't know when the url ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SVG URL contain double quotes and you are adding it within double quote. You have to place it within single quote.

```
background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="8" height="5" viewBox="0 0 8 5" fill="black" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M0.94 0L4 3.09042L7.06 0L8 0.951417L4 5L0 0.951417L0.94 0Z" fill="black"/></svg>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed the quotes to single quotes to be different than the svg double quotes

```
background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="8" height="5" viewBox="0 0 8 5" fill="black" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M0.94 0L4 3.09042L7.06 0L8 0.951417L4 5L0 0.951417L0.94 0Z" fill="black"/></svg');
```